# AAPT: error: '#ffffff' is incompatible with attribute drawable (attr) reference

Tags: android, kotlin, aapt

I'm new to android programming so what I did was I created an application.

I made a backup of the whole application folder so I can repaste it again if ever I had troubles.

Now that I copy and pasted the backup files to the current project folder. 
Everything went nuts.

An error saying

> "AAPT: error: '#ffffff' is incompatible with attribute drawable (attr)
>   reference."
>
> "AAPT: error: resource style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay (aka
>   com.example.reviewerapplication:style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay) not
>   found."
>
> "AAPT: error: attribute navGraph (aka
>   com.example.reviewerapplication:navGraph) not found."

That is just 3 samples of the 100+ errors with the same "AAPT" on it.

Can anyone please help me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `"AAPT: error: '#ffffff' is incompatible with attribute drawable (attr) reference."`

You are using a `color` in a `drawable` attribute. You have to use a `drawable` resources (`@drawable/...`)

> `"AAPT: error: resource style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay (aka com.example.reviewerapplication:style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay) not found."`

You are linking the `@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay` but it doesn't exist in your `res/values/styles.xml` file.

> `"AAPT: error: attribute navGraph (aka com.example.reviewerapplication:navGraph) not found."`

It seems that you have to add in your `build.gradle` some dependencies:

```
dependencies {
  def nav_version = "2.3.0-rc01"

  implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$nav_version"
  implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$nav_version"
}
```

Comment: This actually didn't solve my issue but this helped me in learning what I should have done.

I solved the issue by deleting all those files and layouts that are having the issue. I found out that those files are not used at all while I was working on my current application. Those files were when I was first starting out, like a scratch and I didn't delete those while I was backing up the files to a backup folder. I ended up pasting it back again to the current folder and came out the error. 

Now it's resolved. But thank you so much for these advises, I should have done most of these.